# Omit properties that extends a specific type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the following interface:

```js
interface Entity {
  A: boolean;
  B: string;
  C: number;
  D: never
}
```

I would like to create a type that omits the properties that `extends never`. Something like that:

```js
type FilteredEntity = OmitNever<Entity>; //  = { A: boolean; B: string; C: number };
```

How `OmitNever` should be implemented?

Comment: I updated my answer, I tried it and it works: https://tsplay.dev/wg6qlW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would solve your problem:

```
interface Entity {
  A: boolean;
  B: string;
  C: number;
  D: never
}

type Entries<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]]
}[keyof T]

type EntriesWithValueOfType<T, U> = T extends [any, U] ? T : never;

type EntityNeverEntries = EntriesWithValueOfType<Entries<Entity>, never>

type KeysOfEntries<T> = T extends [infer U, any] ? U : never;

type OmitNever = Omit<Entity, KeysOfEntries<EntityNeverEntries>>
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gWAChlkBBALmQCMB7GgGwjhAG4iSAhSgZzClADmbYsgDClEAFcAtlWjCSAEQkQAbtCIBfIkWwAHFOj7AI3ADwAVAHzIAvHnbIA2gGlkoZAGsIWGjGQWALqUrgA0Aa6BgVpO3r7+QTqE+obg-KYA6pgAFgBqcPSSEADyMBZYBpbhAKo29hbIEAAekCAAJtzOzFg1gcgA-AHIKupQwroVqWCYWAByatBG6Z32SybcWWB5BUWl5ZVrpmZGM1bhIAtQVkkpyC4+3KWH5tZ2Q82tHc6gMNDI1eFun1BtVhsgLqNxslJshitJMPNRm84ZhjhhsOF7lhHjBnmjpthEYs0usrNdCEA)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this

```
// Omit a single property:
type FilteredEntity = Omit<Entity, "D">;
// Equivalent to: {A: boolean, B: string, C: number}
```

And for never

```
type Keys_NeverExcluded<T> = 
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends never ? never : K }[keyof T]
type FilteredEntity = Pick<Entity, Keys_NeverExcluded<Entity>>
```

Now, if you tried something like

```
const p: FilteredEntity = {A: true, B: "test", C: 3, D: null}
```

It will tell you

```
Type '{ A: true; B: string; C: number; D: null; }' is not assignable to type 'FilteredEntity'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'D' does not exist in type 'FilteredEntity'.
```

Playground: https://tsplay.dev/wg6qlW

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't answer my question. I want to infer the never properties. Not to manually typing them...

Comment: Yeah, I updated it :)